# Not able to understand the issue in react dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, user-interface, package.json

I have to use react translation for multiple languages. When I am installing

```
"i18next": "^21.6.3",
"react-i18next": "^11.15.1",
```

it start throwing error.

[image]

this is my i18.js

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import translationEN from '../public/locales/en/translation.json';

// the translations
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: translationEN,
  },
};

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: 'en',

    keySeparator: false, // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // react already safes from xss
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

Below is my `package.json` . I am not able to understand whether it is dependency issue or issue of  `i18 file`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bowser": "^2.1.0",
    "classnames": "^2.1.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "css-hot-loader": "^1.3.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "fbemitter": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.4.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.10",
    "i18next": "^21.6.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.3.5",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.0",
    "react-anything-sortable": "^1.7.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-bootstrap-date-picker-thecodingmachine": "^5.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-native-slider": "^2.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-slider": "^2.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.1.5",
    "react-color": "^2.13.8",
    "react-datepicker": "1.6.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.3",
    "react-i18next": "^11.15.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scrollable-anchor": "^0.6.1",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "react-signature-pad": "^0.0.6",
    "react-spinners": "^0.4.5",
    "react-star-rating": "^1.4.2",
    "react-stepzilla": "^4.6.3",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^5.1.0",
    "react-toastify": "^3.1.0",
    "react-toggle": "^4.0.2",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.1",
    "reactjs-localstorage": "0.0.5",
    "reactstrap": "^4.8.0",
    "reflux": "^6.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "superagent": "^3.8.1",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "xss": "^0.3.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "6.26.0",
    "canvas": "1.6.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "dotenv-cli": "2.0.1",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.3",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "jsdom": "11.2.0",
    "mocha": "^3.3.0",
    "mocha-jsdom": "^1.1.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "1.10.12",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.7",
    "react-tools": "0.13.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "source-map": "^0.6.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  }
```

could you please , please help me on the same.
can you just guide me whether my main dependencies like `react` ,`react-dom`, `i18next` and some others are compatible. even if you dont check for others but please can you check main dependencies. if you can help me to debug only `star-rating.jsx` it will help me to debug others. I am not doing even any changes on this file still it is giving error.

```
export default class StarRating extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ratingCache: {
        pos: 0,
        rating: 0,
      },
      editing: props.editing || true,
      stars: 5,
      rating: 0,
      pos: 0,
      glyph: this.getStars(),
    };
  }

  /**
   * Gets the stars based on ratingAmount
   * @return {string} stars
   */
  getStars() {
    var stars = '';
    var numRating = this.props.ratingAmount;
    for (var i = 0; i < numRating; i++) {
      stars += '\u2605';
    }
    return stars;
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.min = 0;
    this.max = this.props.ratingAmount || 5;
    if (this.props.rating) {
      this.state.editing = this.props.editing || false;
      var ratingVal = this.props.rating;
      this.state.ratingCache.pos = this.getStarRatingPosition(ratingVal);
      this.state.ratingCache.rating = ratingVal;

      this.setState({
        ratingCache: this.state.ratingCache,
        rating: ratingVal,
        pos: this.getStarRatingPosition(ratingVal),
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.root = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.root);
    this.ratingContainer = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.ratingContainer);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    delete this.root;
    delete this.ratingContainer;
  }

  getPosition(e) {
    return e.pageX - this.root.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  }

  applyPrecision(val, precision) {
    return parseFloat(val.toFixed(precision));
  }

  getDecimalPlaces(num) {
    var match = ('' + num).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
    return !match
      ? 0
      : Math.max(
          0,
          (match[1] ? match[1].length : 0) - (match[2] ? +match[2] : 0)
        );
  }

  getWidthFromValue(val) {
    var min = this.min,
      max = this.max;
    if (val <= min || min === max) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (val >= max) {
      return 100;
    }
    return (val / (max - min)) * 100;
  }

  getValueFromPosition(pos) {
    var precision = this.getDecimalPlaces(this.props.step);
    var maxWidth = this.ratingContainer.offsetWidth;
    var diff = this.max - this.min;
    var factor = (diff * pos) / (maxWidth * this.props.step);
    factor = Math.ceil(factor);
    var val = this.applyPrecision(
      parseFloat(this.min + factor * this.props.step),
      precision
    );
    val = Math.max(Math.min(val, this.max), this.min);
    return val;
  }

  calculate(pos) {
    var val = this.getValueFromPosition(pos),
      width = this.getWidthFromValue(val);

    width += '%';
    return { width, val };
  }

  getStarRatingPosition(val) {
    var width = this.getWidthFromValue(val) + '%';
    return width;
  }

  getRatingEvent(e) {
    var pos = this.getPosition(e);
    return this.calculate(pos);
  }

  getSvg() {
    return (
      <svg
        className="react-star-rating__star"
        viewBox="0 0 286 272"
        version="1.1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <polygon
            id="star-flat"
            points="143 225 54.8322122 271.352549 71.6707613 173.176275 0.341522556 103.647451 98.9161061 89.3237254 143 0 187.083894 89.3237254 285.658477 103.647451 214.329239 173.176275 231.167788 271.352549 "
          ></polygon>
        </g>
      </svg>
    );
  }

  handleMouseLeave() {
    this.setState({
      pos: this.state.ratingCache.pos,
      rating: this.state.ratingCache.rating,
    });
  }

  handleMouseMove(e) {
    // get hover position
    var ratingEvent = this.getRatingEvent(e);
    this.updateRating(ratingEvent.width, ratingEvent.val);
  }

  updateRating(width, val) {
    this.setState({
      pos: width,
      rating: val,
    });
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextProps !== this.props) {
      this.updateRating(
        this.getStarRatingPosition(nextProps.rating),
        nextProps.rating
      );
      return true;
    } else {
      return (
        nextState.ratingCache.rating !== this.state.ratingCache.rating ||
        nextState.rating !== this.state.rating
      );
    }
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    // is it disabled?
    if (this.props.disabled) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

    var ratingCache = {
      pos: this.state.pos,
      rating: this.state.rating,
      caption: this.props.caption,
      name: this.props.name,
    };

    this.setState({
      ratingCache: ratingCache,
    });

    this.props.onRatingClick(e, ratingCache);
  }

  treatName(title) {
    if (typeof title === 'string') {
      return title.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('_');
    }
  }

  render() {
    var caption = null;
    var classes = cx({
      'react-star-rating__root': true,
      'rating-disabled': this.props.disabled,
      ['react-star-rating__size--' + this.props.size]: this.props.size,
      'rating-editing': this.state.editing,
    });

    // is there a caption?
    if (this.props.caption) {
      caption = (
        <span className="react-rating-caption">{this.props.caption}</span>
      );
    }

    // are we editing this rating?
    var starRating;
    if (this.state.editing) {
      starRating = (
        <div
          ref="ratingContainer"
          className="rating-container rating-gly-star"
          data-content={this.state.glyph}
          onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove.bind(this)}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave.bind(this)}
          onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
        >
          <div
            className="rating-stars"
            data-content={this.state.glyph}
            style={{ width: this.state.pos }}
          ></div>
          <input
            type="number"
            name={this.props.name}
            value={this.state.ratingCache.rating}
            style={{ display: 'none !important' }}
            min={this.min}
            max={this.max}
            readOnly
          />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      starRating = (
        <div
          ref="ratingContainer"
          className="rating-container rating-gly-star"
          data-content={this.state.glyph}
        >
          <div
            className="rating-stars"
            data-content={this.state.glyph}
            style={{ width: this.state.pos }}
          ></div>
          <input
            type="number"
            name={this.props.name}
            value={this.state.ratingCache.rating}
            style={{ display: 'none !important' }}
            min={this.min}
            max={this.max}
            readOnly
          />
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <span className="react-star-rating">
        <span ref="root" style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} className={classes}>
          {starRating}
        </span>
      </span>
    );
  }
}

StarRating.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  caption: React.PropTypes.string,
  ratingAmount: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  rating: React.PropTypes.number,
  onRatingClick: React.PropTypes.func,
  disabled: React.PropTypes.bool,
  editing: React.PropTypes.bool,
  size: React.PropTypes.string,
};

StarRating.defaultProps = {
  step: 0.5,
  ratingAmount: 5,
  onRatingClick() {},
  disabled: false,
};
```

Comment: I'd probably start with with stacktrace before going down other rabbit-holes. What is happening in `start-rating.jsx`?

Comment: Thank you @DrewReese .I am not doing any changes on this file still it is giving error. I have attached the file code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'string')

I believe the issue is where you are declaring your proptypes for `StarRating`.

```
StarRating.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  caption: React.PropTypes.string,
  ratingAmount: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  rating: React.PropTypes.number,
  onRatingClick: React.PropTypes.func,
  disabled: React.PropTypes.bool,
  editing: React.PropTypes.bool,
  size: React.PropTypes.string,
};
```

`PropTypes` were moved from `React` a long time ago, back in React v15 if I'm not mistaken.

[Typechecking with PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

> **Note:**
>
> `React.PropTypes` has moved into a different package since React
> v15.5. Please use [the prop-types library instead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types).
>
> We provide [a codemod script](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-reactproptypes) to automate the conversion.

You are already using the `PropTypes` package:

```
"prop-types": "^15.5.10",
```

So I think the solution here is to import `PropTypes` and simply remove the `React.` prefix:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

...

```
StarRating.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  caption: PropTypes.string,
  ratingAmount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  rating: PropTypes.number,
  onRatingClick: PropTypes.func,
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  editing: PropTypes.bool,
  size: PropTypes.string,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining propTypes seems wrong as per React current version, no need to extract propTypes from React as it comes with a separate package.

So, the correct syntax for declaring the props would be

```
  StarRating.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  caption: PropTypes.string,
  ratingAmount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  rating: PropTypes.number,
  onRatingClick: PropTypes.func,
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  editing: PropTypes.bool,
  size: PropTypes.string,
  };
```